# Subdomains with Apache Virtualhost

Tags: apache

I have a server and registered a domain - say **mysite.com** - that is pointing to the IP address of the server. I tested the setup with a django project in the default.conf file. This works without a flaw, but my goal is to move this django site to a subdomain. As this didn't work as expected, I tried to get a minimal example working with a redirect.

This is what I have:

**sites-available/sub.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.mysite.com
  RedirectPermanent / https://google.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the site via `a2ensite sub` and `service apache2 reload`. When visiting sub.mysite.com all get is

> Server not found

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `sub.mysite.com` pointing to the IP address of the server?

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid :D Thanks for your help.